# How does this simple program not represent recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion

How does this "not" demonstrate recursion?   It is a simple high/low find where I set "mid" to be the guess of the program's randomly selected number within the range.  I am in a pissing match with an instructor.  What do you think?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // define variables
int left = 1, mid, range, secret, y = 0;

// query user defined range, assign to variable range
cout << "Please enter top of range: " << endl;
cin >> range;

// seed random number generator with time
srand(time(NULL));

// generate secret number based between left and range
secret = rand() % range;

    do {
        // define and assign primary value of mid updating on each 
iteration
        mid = ((range + left) / 2);

        if (mid > secret) {
            // set range to mid
            range = mid;
            // iterate
            y++;

        } else if (mid < secret) {
            // set left to mid
            left = mid;
            // iterate
            y++;

        } else {
                // escape condition met
                cout << "Found secret number " << secret << " in " << y 
<< " tries. " << endl;
                return 0;
            }

        } while (mid != secret);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because as your own comment says, it is iterative.  And from a technical point of view, main() cannot be called recursively (or at all) in C++.

Comment: To know recursion, you first must know recursion

Comment: It does not demonstrate recursion since nothing is being called recursively. Simple as that.

Comment: Please [don't use rand()](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful). We have [better things](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) these days. And if you *do* use `rand()`, `srand(time(NULL));` is a *horrible* seed - you can do better than that.

Comment: `secret = rand() % range;` most likely introduces bias in your number - research "pigeon hole principle". Or just use a [std::uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Comment: `using namespace std;` - Usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

"Recursion occurs when a thing is defined in terms of itself or of its type."  Thus, a function that calls itself is recursive. A simple loop is not.

Comment: *Taken from Wikipedia.

Comment: ... or from the same place Wikipedia stole it from :)

Comment: Thanks all... I posted while pissed.. the linear nature of this solution should have been my first flag.  I'm a dummy.  ;)